# Managing customized citation style in biblatex numeric-comp

Tags: bibliographies

After using Biblatex numeric-comp style for managing my citations and implementing numerous modular changes found here I could not manage to alter my citation style to fit my requirements. 
I am stuck at finding a way to shift the year after the journal name and altering punctuation to something like this:

> NAME, TITLE. JOURNAL. YEAR; Volume(Issue):pages. Doi

Here are two examples from my bibliography:

```
@article{Hasegawa2007,
author = {Hasegawa T},
title = {{Heterotopic vascularized murine cardiac transplantation to study graft arteriopathy}},
journal = {Nat Protoc},
volume = {2},
number = {3},
pages = {471},
year = {2007},
month = {Mar},
```

}

```
@article{Steeds2011,
author = {Steeds RP},
title = {{Echocardiography: frontier imaging in cardiology}},
journal = {Br J Radiol},
volume = {84},
number = {3},
pages = {237--44},
year = {2011},
month = {Dec},
```

}

So I would like it to look something like this:

> Steeds RP, Echocardiography: frontier imaging in cardiology. Br J Radiol. 2011; 
>   84(3):237-44.

I am afraid I cannot provide a good minimal working example since I lack the experience in distilling my mix of copied macros into somethings simpler.

Is there a simple solution to switching the allocated slots of these? And how do I change the individual seperators into comma/dots/semicolons for my desired format? Also, how can I get rid of the added "no." before the numbering of the issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please show us a short compilable code how you build your bibliography. Do not for get to add two bib entrys to your question too!

Comment: Is this question answered with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457281/35864?