# How to add deleted periods in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, macros

Unfortunately, it seems I have replaced the periods after my "Title" and "Journal" fields with commata, even though I would like them there.
So how can I bring back periods before and after my "Journal" entries in Biblatex using numeric-comp settings?

```
@article{Steeds2011,
author = {Steeds RP},
title = {{Echocardiography: frontier imaging in cardiology}},
journal = {Br J Radiol},
volume = {84},
number = {3},
pages = {237--44},
year = {2011},
month = {Dec},

}
```

In the end, I would like the .bib entry below to look something like this:

> Steeds RP, Echocardiography: frontier imaging in cardiology. Br J Radiol. 2011; 84(3):237-44.

However, I cannot figure out at what point I had the periods after the "title"
abd "journal" fields replaced with commata!

Here are my currently implemented macros:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}

\renewcommand\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
page = {},
pages = {},
}


\renewbibmacro{in:}{\addcomma\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number}{%
\isdot
\printfield{volume}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
\iffieldundef{number}{}{%
\printtext{no\adddot\addnbthinspace}%
}%
\printfield{(number)}%
\setunit{\addcolon\space}%
\printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
 \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addperiod}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}


\newbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit}



\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addperiod}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \newunit}




% No dot before number of articles
\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
}{%
}{}{}

% Number of articles in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately, the code formatting is a bit off (code can be marked with `{}`, it seems you also pressed the `""` button). Can you please paste the code anew, so we can be sure line breaks etc. are right? It would also help if you could turn your code into a so-called minimal working example (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864), that allows us to understand your problem more quickly.

Comment: I just tried to paste the code from the reference settings anew! I'm afraid I can't build a working minimal example at the moment, but is there any way I could simply fix up another macro to simply add those two periods needed after the title and the journal's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit unusual, I have removed redundant and completely unnecessary code and have tried to modernise the rest. I have not removed everything I found questionable, but the result should be slightly more `biblatex`-y now.

The periods can be added in `\renewbibmacro{in:}` (instead of the comma) and in the second `\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}` (instead of a space).

Note that `author = {Steeds RP}` is very wrong, the correct input would be `author = {Steeds, R. P.}`. You then let `biblatex` take care of the formatting.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, giveninits, terseinits]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}


\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}


\renewcommand\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{\addperiod\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}} 

\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
}{%
}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Steeds2011,
  author  = {Steeds, R. P.},
  title   = {Echocardiography: frontier imaging in cardiology},
  journal = {Br J Radiol},
  volume  = {84},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {237--44},
  year    = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,Steeds2011}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson E and Ryde U, Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry. 1998; 19(4): 377–395, doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//Steeds RP, Echocardiography: frontier imaging in cardiology. Br J Radiol. 2011; 84(3): 237–44.]